# single page javascript send data AND pull data from mysql via php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to make a dynamic form which retrives data.  How can I use javascript to load a value from a mysql database?

I understand that it must use php in some way, and I know how to query the database and assign the value to a php variable, but I have no idea what to do after that...any advice?

the goal is to have someone enter their orderid say, then the datbase auto pulls down and enters their last invoice in the field below it after they click GO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the W3 schools AJAX (which is what you are trying to use) tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

It will walk you through using AJAX and give you example code so you can do specifically what you want to do and other simple AJAX functions you may want to do.

Comment: do I need to download any special software to my hosting to use ajax or is it just a name?

Comment: Generally speaking, AJAX is just a buzzword people use to talk about Javascript that does magical things, including talking to serverside scripts.  You want to learn about those Javascript functions, and Zak's link will get you started.